# How to use AJAX on bootstrap-duallistbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using this, but no documentation at all/ajax example
http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

And even tried like this

```
$('#bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_SelectItem').append('<option value="test" data-sortindex="'+i+'">Test, Test</option>');
```

and when I click this button, the appended gone.

[image]